# Minimum capacitor voltage?

Tags: capacitor

Is there a minimum voltage needed to charge a capacitor? How about for an ultracapacitor? I'm thinking there is not, but I seem to remember someone saying that ultracapacitors were better for use with small solar cells (toy size) because they would be able to charge at a very low voltage as opposed to regular capacitors which had a higher voltage minimum. But, in my research I can find nothing to confirm that.

Answer (score 5):

No, capacitors will charge to **any voltage** you apply, as long the voltage **does not exceed the rating**.

Supercapacitors just have lower voltage limits -- meaning how much **maximum voltage** you can apply across them -- than regular capacitors.

Comment: And because of the higher capacitance of the supercapacitor, the minimum voltage you need to store a certain required amount of energy is indeed lower.

Answer (score 3):

A perfect capacitor would not have a minimum operating voltage.  However most capacitors are not perfect.  Polarized types, especially electrolytics, may have altered characteristics at very low voltages as they have internal chemical layers that need to build up.  They also have some leakage current that can be voltage and temperature dependent.  The best answer is to consult the manufacturer's specifications.